# How to get song info with "kind = music" (iTunes API)?

Tags: metadata, itunes, itunesartwork, itunes-search-api

I'm trying to get songs info with iTunes API. For example if I make a query like this: `https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=no+hero+elisa` the problem is that the `kind` (in response) is `music-video`, while on iTunes Store there is the song only (https://itunes.apple.com/it/album/no-hero/id1089487160?i=1089487517). If I use the `entity` attribute like this: `https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=no+hero+elisa&entity=song` there are no results!

My problem is I need to get the song artwork, in iTunes there's this one http://a5.mzstatic.com/eu/r30/Music69/v4/d0/2e/66/d02e6666-1a7e-f5bc-bf7d-60192700dc4a/cover170x170.jpeg but in the JSON response there is another one which is wrong! Can anyone help me? I only know the song title and the name of the artist, I don't have any iTunes ID..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Search API has started returning the song now that you were looking for. Here is where you were running into an issue:

By default, the Search API searches the USA store.  The song is available in the USA store starting today. If you wanted to get the Italian store result you should have searched like this:

https://itunes.apple.com/it/search?term=no+hero+elisa&entity=song

Note the /it/ in the base URL defining Italy as the storefront.

Comment: Thanks you! This is the problem.. Anyway I think this is a stupid think, how can I previously know the region of the song??? 